# How to define ssh private key location

Tags: openssh, sshd, private-key

I know that you can globally set per users authorized key files with this line inside `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/%u
```

Is it possible to do something similar like this but with private key files?
I want to change the private key location for some users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The private key file location is a client configuration item. If you want to do it for some users, it's best to add it to their `/home/username/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host *
    IdentityFile /path/to/key.file
```

Globally on the system it can be configured in the SSH client config at `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`